# mute all audio when users tab away from the site

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible to mute embedded  ( tag) audio when the user leaves the site (goes on another tab). I've seen this with other websites where they change their title when the users leave. I'd expect you'd need a bit of javascript and jquery to do this.

Comment: Please post the code you've tried and the sort of audio you want to disable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can listen to the `blur` event on the `window` object to detect when the user switches tabs or apps:

```
window.addEventListener('blur', () => console.log('blur'))
```

Take care though, as this fires on all occasions when the window loses focus, including for example, pressing ctrl+f to open the find dialog or clicking on an extension popup.

As to audio, assuming you are using standard html5 `<audio>` element, you can set  the `muted` property to true:

```
document.getElementById('my-audio-tag').muted = true
```